# Gradle source dependency - Unable to find module with Gradle path

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to leverage https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies so that Project A can consume Project B from source.

I started with the recommended setup in Project A's settings.gradle:

```
 sourceControl {
      gitRepository(uri("ssh://git@github.com/isupatches/bar.git")) {
          producesModule("com.isupatches:bar")
      }
  }
```

And added this to the module .gradle:

```
 implementation('com.isupatches:bar') {
     version {
         branch = 'test-branch'
     }
 }
```

But I am receiving this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to find module with Gradle path ':bar' (needed by module 'foo'.)
```

Here is Project B's settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name='Bar'

include ':bar'
project(':bar').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, 'bar')
```

The project structure for Project B is a typical Android app with a library module:

```
project    
  |- bar
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

**UPDATE**

I found that if I update Gradle to Gradle 6.0.1 that I see the source code downloaded into the .gradle/vcs-1 directory, but it seems the classes and code is not available on the classpath.

Comment: I have a similar issue but i can't even get the source to download, i get an error, module not found. Is projectB just a normal java library. I posed an issue here github.com/isupatches/bar.git